# I'm trying to work out a way to create and IF function to determine if filters applied to a table in VBA return an Empty table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an excel workbook that has a dashboard on the front page of it. when two dates are selected from a drop down and the "refresh data" button is pressed, it runs a macro that fills in all the charts and tables on the dashboard page based on data tables in other worksheets within the workbook.

I'm trying to add a layer of dynamism so that if a date is selected where not all information, or even any information, is to be found, it lets the user know. (some information can be late coming to the work book)

So far I've tried a few ways with the closest maybe being the following options, but none of them work properly.

The beginning code is

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim DataM As Variant
Dim DataY As Variant
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim DD1 As OLEObject
Dim DD2 As OLEObject
Dim i As Byte

Set ws1 = Worksheets("KPI Dashboard")
Set DD1 = ws1.OLEObjects("DMonth") 'this is the month input
Set DD2 = ws1.OLEObjects("Dyear") 'this is the year input

Set DataM = DD1.Object
Set DataY = DD2.Object

'part 1 is for utilisation
Set ws2 = Worksheets("People Info")
ws2.ListObjects("Utilisation").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=DataM.Value
ws2.ListObjects("Utilisation").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=DataY.Value
```

My first attempt was to count the rows in the databodyrange, but every time I tried that I would get an error saying there was no cells. I know I oculd normally put an "on error" line of code, but I want it to highlight to the user that there is a table missing data and then go onto the next table and keep going. I don't know of any ways in which I could dynamically have error responses in one function to the same error.

My second attempt was to just count the tables overall rows, with a msgbox to say there was no data like below:

```
If ws2.ListObjects("Utilisation").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count = 1 Then
    If MsgBox("It Looks like we have no data for Utilisation, please fill it in and run it again. do you want to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ws2.ListObjects("Utilisation").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    GoTo S1P2
End If
```

But it always returns the count of rows as 1, even when I can see that it clearly has 5 or 6 rows in it.

So the last thing I tried was to select the area, and see if I could count that selection to greater success, but again it would still return 1, even on the count

Can anyone think of a better way to try it?

I have also tried using the `IsEmpty()` function and a handful of others like that but can't seem to get it to work. it either says there are no cells in the databody range, because they have been queried out or it says there is 1 row in the table range, even when there isn't.

Any help on how to make it work, or even a different avenue with which to look down would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you tried the `LastRow` function?  This plus counting should do it

Comment: I did try that, yes, but when the filters are put in to return an empty table it just goes to the hidden last row of the data

Comment: Depending on how many rows the sheet has, you could iterate through the rows in VBA?